# Offline Euler problem viewer (text only)

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a single page web application (that should work offline, without a database, etc.) using bootstrap and JavaScript to act as an Euler question viewer (text only). It simply renders the text taken from the text file (http://kmkeen.com/local-euler/project_euler.txt).

**How it works:**

Content of the text file is kept as a string. It Extract questions and answers from it using a regex. That is why `eulerDb` is a string. Also `initialize_euler` is called at `onload` event.

```
var eulerDb = "--EULER DATABASE--"
                + "Project Euler is protected under\n"
                + "Attribution-Non-Commercial-Share Alike 2.0 UK: England & Wales\n"
                + "\n"
                + "^sup and [sub] are frequently use for subscripts/superscripts.\n"
                + "Many symbols are utf8, my apologies if you are on a 7-bit TTY.\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Solutions are hashed with md5sum\n"
                + "echo -n 'myanswer' | md5sum\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "generated on 2014-6-29 at 15:46\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Problem 1\n"
                + "=========\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "   If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5,\n"
                + "   we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.\n"
                + "\n"
                + "   Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.\n"
                + "\n"
                + "   \n"
                + "   Answer: e1edf9d1967ca96767dcc2b2d6df69f4\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Problem 2\n"
                + "=========\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "   Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the\n"
                + "   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:\n"
                + "\n"
                + "                     1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...\n"
                + "\n"
                + "   By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not\n"
                + "   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.\n"
                + "\n"
                + "   \n"
                + "   Answer: 4194eb91842c8e7e6df099ca73c38f28\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
```

It is also hosted [here](http://jadogg.github.io/OfflineEuler/). Repository is located [here](https://github.com/JaDogg/OfflineEuler/tree/gh-pages).

[image: How it looks like]

I want the JavaScript section reviewed.

```
var eulerQuestions = [];
var questionCount = 0;
var currentAnswer = "?";

function is_correct(answer) {
    if (currentAnswer == "?") {
        alert("Sorry I do not know the answer");
        return;
    }

    var yourHash = md5(answer);
    if (yourHash == currentAnswer) {
        alert('Correct');
    } else {
        alert('Incorrect');
    }
}

function initialize_euler() {
    eulerDb = eulerDb.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '$NEW');

    var matches;

    var re = /Problem\s+\d+.*?=+(.*?)Answer:\s+([a-f0-9]+|\?)/g;
    while (matches = re.exec(eulerDb)) { 
        eulerQuestions.push([matches[1], matches[2]]);
        questionCount++;
    }

    build_question_buttons();
    render_question(0);
}

function build_question_buttons() {
    var button_temp = '<a onclick="render_question($1);" class="btn btn-default" role="button">$2</a>';
    var generated_html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questionCount; i++) {
        var temp_str = button_temp.replace('$1', i);
        temp_str = temp_str.replace('$2', i + 1);
        generated_html += temp_str;
    }

    document.getElementById("questionButtons").innerHTML = generated_html;
}

function render_question(questionId) {
    var question = eulerQuestions[questionId][0].replace(/(?:\$NEW)/g, '\n');
    currentAnswer = eulerQuestions[questionId][1];

    if (currentAnswer == "?") {
        question += "\n\nNote: Answer is not available."
    }
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = question;
    document.getElementById("questionNumber").innerHTML = "Problem " + (questionId + 1);

}
```

Related HTML content:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row well">
                <div class="col-md-4 well well-sm pre-scrollable">
                    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
                        <div class="button-container" id="questionButtons">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <form role="form" id="questionForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="questionNumber">Problem 01</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <pre id="question" style="">
                            </pre>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Answer:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer">
                        </div>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" onclick="is_correct(document.getElementById('answer').value)">
                                Test Answer
                            </a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

<sub><sub>This is based on http://kmkeen.com/local-euler/2008-07-16-07-33-00.html. Thanks @200_success for the link.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too big for a comment, but I have reason to believe your links are not working.

A random example, challenge 54:

```
The file, [1]poker.txt, contains one-thousand random hands dealt to two
players. Each line of the file contains ten cards (separated by a single
space): the first five are Player 1's cards and the last five are Player
2's cards. You can assume that all hands are valid (no invalid characters
or repeated cards), each player's hand is in no specific order, and in
each hand there is a clear winner.

How many hands does Player 1 win?


Visible links
1. poker.txt
```

You state there are 'Visible links'. Where? Your links do not appear to be working.